# Can I inherit a Command class from ICommand rather than have multiple instances of ICommand on one class?

Tags: wpf, mef, icommand

It seems much neater to me to implement a command in a class that represents that command, and derives from ICommand. This way I can also export and import commands in an MEF composite application.

Is this possible, or feasible? Is there a known pattern for accomplishing this?

Comment: Not clear, what you are asking here. `ICommand` is an interface. You certainly can create your own classes that implement this interface.

Comment: I'm not asking if I implement an interface. I'm asking if implementing each command as a class that inherits `ICommand`, with allowance for MEF import and export is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well this answers your question, since I don't know much about MEF.

There is no need to have direct references to command instances on your class, but you do need some way of presenting a binding source that returns one to a view. You can build a menu by binding a MenuItem's ItemsSource to a property that returns a dynamically generated IEnumerable of commands, for example.

You could also use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to get a command on-demand for some arbitrary identifier:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=CommandId, Converter={StaticResource CommandConverter}}" />
```

Or pass the identifier directly from XAML through Binding.Source:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Source=DesiredCommand, Converter={StaticResource CommandConverter}}" />
```

In this case the string "DesiredCommand" would be passed to the converter.